# Delay in code changes on custom pages in drupal 8 in a docker environment

Tags: 8

There is a delay between saving code changes in a controller and being able to view them in the browser.

This is frustrating (to say the least) and makes it very hard to develop and debug module code.

I have tried setting up a development environment in docker and it's working quite well except for this nasty and unpredictable delay.

For a minimal example I tried installing the Hello World example module from the [Prepare a Module skeleton](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/prepare-a-module-skeleton) guide.

My (minimal, but complete) setup is available here: https://github.com/glaux/drupal8docker.

#### To replicate the delay

- Get the site up and running.
- Log in as `admin` with pass `123` on http://localhost:8090
- Navigate to /hello
- Change the markup in the file `/docker/project/modules/D8HWexample/src/Controller/HelloController.php`
- Refresh /hello - the changes will show up after between 5 and 300 seconds.

#### What I've tried

I've tried disabling all the caches by following the official guides. When making css changes to a custom theme (not included in the minimal repo above) the code changes are visible immediately, so this is not a cache problem I believe.

This is also emphasized by the fact that rebuilding the cache via the interface, drush and/or drupal console seems to have no effect on this delay.

In a similar manner I've tried disabling the browser cache (by opening the dev console on chrome). This have no effect either, nor have clearing the browser cache manually.

How can I get rid of this delay, what am I doing wrong here?

#### Edit

I think Clive could be right that this is possibly on the file system level. Here is an excerpt from the docker-compose file:

```
volumes:
  - ./docker/project/modules:/var/www/html/modules
  - ./docker/project/themes:/var/www/html/themes
  - ./docker/project/libraries:/var/www/html/libraries
  - ./docker/project/profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
  - ./docker/project/sites:/var/www/html/sites
  # Add anonymous volumes to exclude cache files explicitly
  - /var/www/html/sites/default/files/js
  - /var/www/html/sites/default/files/css
  - /var/www/html/sites/default/files/php
```

The files are added as explicit volumes, and the changes I make to `HelloController.php` are reflected in the image. I'm running this on Windows 10. Could this be the culprit, and how can I test this?

Comment: Sure it's not Varnish or another reverse proxy cache? I don't have this problem in half a dozen Drupal 8 sites, a couple of them sitting on Docker images, so it's likely to be something specific to your environment. Also are you editing in the docker image or via NFS/etc? If NFS, check that the delay isn't at the file system level

Comment: It's very possible it's at the file system level, any ideas to how I can check that? I'll add some sections of the docker-compose file to the question.

Comment: Er....good question! How about writing a quick script on the docker image with a file watcher, which logs the current time every time one of the files in your web folder changes. Then you can `tail -f` the log file, edit a file in Windows, and see how long it takes to register. Feels like there would a better way but that'll do in a pinch. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475252/bash-script-watch-folder-execute-command for hints

Comment: Which makes the question off-topic for Drupal Answers?

Comment: "It's very possible it's at the file system level" 
300 seconds is too slow even for the slowest file system though

Comment: Big change it is opcache as well. Your image appears to be based on [drupal:8.4.3-apache](https://github.com/docker-library/drupal/blob/master/8.4/apache/Dockerfile), which sets an opcache revalidate frequency of 60 seconds. This means that if you access the same file within 60 seconds, it will be served from RAM instead.

Comment: @Neograph734 That's it! With opcache disabled the delay disappears. Thanks a ton! If you write it as an answer I'll make sure to accept it. I don't know if this question is out of scope for drupal answers, but I believe this should be documented somewhere at least.

Comment: What host your are Dockering on? Linux? Windows? Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image is based on [drupal:8.4.3-apache](https://github.com/docker-library/drupal/blob/master/8.4/apache/Dockerfile), which sets an opcache revalidate frequency of 60 seconds:

```
# set recommended PHP.ini settings
# see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php
RUN { \
        echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
        echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
        echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
        echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=60'; \
        echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
        echo 'opcache.enable_cli=1'; \
    } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini
```

This means that if you access the same file within 60 seconds, it will be served from RAM instead.

Comment: Hah, I've been using docker for mac for months now and just dealing with this infuriating delay. Once I discovered this I was so happy. I turned down the revalidate freq to 2 seconds instead of 60 and performance tanked. File access is now ~2.5x slower. :(

Comment: @Brian I am not an expert, but I think setting it to 2 seconds might even be worse than disabling it entirely. PHP would need to check all files used in a request (which are a lot with all different classes) and see if they have changed in the last 2 seconds. If a request takes a little longer, I can imagine some files even being checked multiple times. I have disabled it entirely in my dev and speeds are acceptable, otherwise try something like 10 seconds.